# Zsh configuration line navigation

Tags: zsh

I am using VSCode and I have this nice behaviour: when I do `alt-right-arrow` from the end of the line, it stops at

```
foo/bar/test_wait_what
    ^   ^    ^    ^
```

and when I do `delete+alt`, it deletes `what`, then `_`, then `wait`, etc.

I would like to do more or less the same with zsh (without oh-my-zsh because I am already using zimfw). Out of the box, it seems that it does not consider `_` as a word separator and for `/`, it deletes it at the same time.

I found some similar issues where they suggest to use `select-word-style bash`, but bash does not have the behaviour I want when deleting.

Also, I found it hard to find clear information on zsh, examples and so on, so if you have any suggestions on how I could have found an answer by myself, do not hesitate.

Comment: Note: The question [has also been asked (and answered) on unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/565757).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `~/.zshrc` file:

```sh
# Enable additional matching syntax.
# It's required for the function below, but you'll want this anyway.
# According to many, it's THE killer feature of Zsh.
# It makes no sense to me that this is disabled by default.
# See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation
setopt extendedglob

# Override the existing widget that's bound to alt-backspace.
zle -N backward-kill-word
backward-kill-word() {
  if [[ $LBUFFER[-1] == [[:WORD:]] ]]; then
    # If there's a word char left of the cursor, use the old widget.
    zle .backward-kill-word
  else
    # Select all consecutive non-word chars left of the cursor.
    (( MARK = ${#LBUFFER%%[^[:WORD:]]##} - 1 ))

    # Kill them. 
    zle .kill-region
  fi
}
```

I prefer my solution above over the one given at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/565761/413610, because mine preserves the "kill" functionality of <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>backspace</kbd>, meaning that you can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to paste ("yank") the deleted text, if necessary.